# How to customize IEEEeqnarraybox tables?

Tags: tables, matrices, ieeetran, hf-tikz

The package [ieeetrantools](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools) provides access to the environment IEEEeqnarraybox which can be used to create nice tables and matrices. Since it is meant for IEEE journals, it doesn't provide options to add some "style" (dashed lines, background color for rows/columns, ...). How could one customize tables/matrices created with this environment?

For example, I recreated a table from the [ieeetran manual](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) and tried to add a background color to a row with the package [hf-tikz](https://ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz). The result is not great. The border hf-tikz adds is to thick and it messes with the right-hand side vertical and horizontal lines of the table.

[image: comparison of two tables where the right table has hf-tikz applied to the second row]

Code:

```
%! TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[fontsize = 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}

\tikzset{style green/.style={
    set fill color=green!50!lime!60,
    set border color=black,
  },
  hor/.style={
    above left offset={0.0,0.7},
    below right offset={-0.1,0.-0.55},
    #1
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Possible $\Omega$ Functions}
        \label{table_omega}
        \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[\IEEEeqnarraystrutmode\IEEEeqnarraystrutsizeadd{2pt}{1pt}]{v/c/v/c/v}
            \IEEEeqnarrayrulerow\\
            &\mbox{Range}&&\Omega(m)&\\
            \IEEEeqnarraydblrulerow\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayseprow[3pt]\\
            &x < 0&&\Omega(m)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m}K^{-i}& \IEEEeqnarraystrutsize{0pt}{0pt}\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayseprow[3pt]\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayrulerow\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayseprow[3pt]\\
            &x \ge 0&&\Omega(m)=\sqrt{m}\hfill& \IEEEeqnarraystrutsize{0pt}{0pt}\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayseprow[3pt]\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayrulerow
        \end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
    \end{table}

\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Possible $\Omega$ Functions}
        \label{table_omega2}
        \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[\IEEEeqnarraystrutmode\IEEEeqnarraystrutsizeadd{2pt}{1pt}]{v/c/v/c/v}
            \IEEEeqnarrayrulerow\\
            &\mbox{Range}&&\Omega(m)&\\
            \IEEEeqnarraydblrulerow\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayseprow[3pt]\\
            \tikzmarkin[disable rounded corners=true,hor=style green]{row}&x < 0&&\Omega(m)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m}K^{-i}& \tikzmarkend{row} \IEEEeqnarraystrutsize{0pt}{0pt}\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayseprow[3pt]\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayrulerow\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayseprow[3pt]\\
            &x \ge 0&&\Omega(m)=\sqrt{m}\hfill& \IEEEeqnarraystrutsize{0pt}{0pt}\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayseprow[3pt]\\
            \IEEEeqnarrayrulerow
        \end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can obtain this layout without `tikz` and `IEEtrantools` in a very simple way.

Comment: ....or using nicematrix package.

Answer (score 2):

For information, here is how to do easily such a table with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=3pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=3pt}
\doublerulesepcolor{white}

$\begin{NiceArray}{cl}[vlines,code-before = \rowcolor{green!15}{2}]
\hline
\text{Range}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\Omega(m)} \\
\hline\hline
x < 0&\Omega(m)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m}K^{-i} \\
\hline
x \ge 0&\Omega(m)=\sqrt{m} \\
\hline
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

With such a code, you won't have artefacts as in the PDF viewers as you have sometimes if you use only the tools of `colortbl`.

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Comment: Great...thanks for the +1 on my comment.